# Cannot show toggle icon of FontAwesomeIcon in React

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

I have a problem with showing a *toggle off icon* in my React app:
The icon is not appearing on the screen.
How can I fix that?

Here is my code snippet shown below.

```
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="fa-solid fa-toggle-off" onClick={switchTheme}/>
```

Comment: Please refer to [Docs](https://fontawesome.com/v5/docs/web/use-with/react#icon-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the doc it's not exactly how you display a FontAwesome object

You have 2 possible methods :

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={["fas", "toggle-off"]} />
```

or

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {faToggleOff} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faToggleOff} />
```